# add " characters in write function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that emits this output

```
file.write(row['time'] + "{application=" + row['application'] + ",runtime=" + str(row['runtime']) + "} " + row['value'] + "\n")
```

output:

```
folder_put_time{application=app1,runtime=1231231231} 17
```

I want the format to be as following:

```
folder_put_time{application="app1", runtime="1231231231"} 19
```

How can I add the `"` sign in code? + `"/""` didn't work for me

Thanks

Comment: have you tried scaping it? `\"`

Comment: you mean file.write(row['time'] + "{application=" +  "\" + row['application'] + ",runtime=" + str(row['runtime']) + "} " + row['value'] + "\n") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is already in a dict (or a mapping object anyway), I think **the cleanest option here** is to use [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map)  (though the double `{{` `}}` to escape the other quotes are a bit ugly still:)

```
file.write('{time}{{application="{application}",runtime="{runtime}"}} {value}\n'.format_map(row))
```

You could use `\"` to escape quotes:

```
file.write(row['time'] + "{application=\"" + row['application'] + "\",runtime=\"" + str(row['runtime']) + "\"} " + row['value'] + "\n")
```

or use a single-quoted string and just use plain `"` within the string:

```
file.write(row['time'] + '{application="' + row['application'] + '",runtime="' + str(row['runtime']) + '"} ' + row['value'] + '\n')
```

You could also use an f-string for less `str()` casts, but accessing dicts within an f-string is a bit ugly (and curly braces need to be escaped by doubling).

```
file.write(f'{row["time"]}{{application=\"{row["application"]}\",runtime=\"{row["runtime"]}\"}} {row["value"]}\n')
```

Comment: Using this format I still get this output : 
folder_put_time{application=app3,runtime=1651495921} 5045

Comment: @Stat.Enthus I'm... quite sure you don't get that output with this code, not with any of the options presented.

Comment: This is the entire write to file part 
`
with open('output_dev.text', 'w') as file:
    for index, row in result_df.iterrows():
        row = {'time': 'a', 'runtime': 'b', 'application': 'c', 'value': 'z'}
        file.write('{time}{{application="{application}",runtime="{runtime}"}} {value}\n'.format_map(row))
    file.close()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not looking at the right file or something then, since there is no way that _won't_ print the quotes.

Comment: Correct, mistake on my side. Thanks!!